# How to change startup type and task to start/stop services from csv file?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have the following csv file:

```
Server,Service,Startup Type,Task
server1,SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER),automatic,start
server2,"SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER), SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER) CEIP",Manual,stop
```

I have the following script but it uses built-in `Stop-Service` or `Start-Service` for now.

I want to allow the flexibility to define all parameters in the csv file and the service is started/stopped based on what the csv file has, as well as setting the `startup type` to a different `startup type` if its changed/different from csv file and current state on the server(s).

```
$csvFile = Import-CSV .\SSAS_services.csv

ForEach ($Server in $csvFile)
{   Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Stop-Service $args[0] } -ComputerName $Server.Server -ArgumentList $Server.Service.Split(",")
}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60

ForEach ($service in (($csvFile.Count - 1)..0))
{   Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Stop-Service $args[0] } -ComputerName $csvFile[$service].Server -ArgumentList $csvFile[$service].Service.Split(",")  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$using` to read a local variable in a remote session, see the [about_remote_variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6) section.

I'm assuming you want to do the following on the remote macines:

- Stop the service
- Adapt the startup type
- Start the service

So the code should approp. look like:

```
$rows = Import-CSV .\SSAS_services.csv

ForEach ($row in $rows)
{   
    # Stop the service on the remote machine
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Stop-Service $using:row.Service } -ComputerName    $row.Server -ArgumentList $row
    Start-Sleep 60
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { 
         # Set the startup type on the remote machine
         Set-Service $using:row.Service -StartupType $using:row."Startup Type"
         Start-Service $using:row.Service 
    } -ComputerName    $row.Server -ArgumentList $row   
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: your code is close to what im looking for :). i dont want to follow a sequence stop > adapt >start. i only want to do whatever is defined in the csv file :). so there should be some if/switch statements. for example, in my csv file, server1 is set to start as the task. if the service is already started, then it simply doesnt affect it, or maybe just return to a log file that its already started for that server. similarly for the startup type, if the service is already manual, and csv says manual, then could append to the log file saying the service is manual already, for examp

Comment: so the script should only affects services based on whats set in the csv file. if server2 is defined to stop services, then the script should stop it. if it says to restart then the script should restart. etc...no hardcoded sequence in the script :).